# how to process hundreds of JMS message from 2 queues, response time of 1 second and 1 minute respectively

Tags: multithreading, jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

I have business requirement where I have to process messages in a certain priority say priority1 and priority2

We have decided to use 2 JMS queues where priority1 messages will be sent to priority1Queue and priority2 messages will be sent to priority2Queue.

Response time for priority1Queue messages is that the moment message is in Queue, I need to read, process and send the response back to say another queue in 1 second. This means I should immediately process these messages the moment they are in priority1Queue, and I will have hundreds of such messages coming in per second on priority1Queue so I will definitely need to have multiple concurrent consumers consuming messages on this queue so that they can be processed immediately when they are in the queue(consumed and processed within 1 second).

Response time for priority2Queue messages is that I need to read, process and send the response back to say another queue in 1 minute. So the response time of priority2 is lower to priority1 messages however I still need to respond back in a minute.

Can you suggest best possible approach for this so that I can concurrently read messages from both the queue and give higher priority to priority1 messages so that each priority1 message can be read and processed in 1 second. 
Mainly how it can be read and fed to a processor so that the next message can be read and so on.

I need to write a java based component that does the reading and processing.

I also need to ensure this component is highly available and doesn't result in OutOfMemory, I will be having this component running across multiple JVMS and multiple application servers thus I can have multiple clusters running this Java component

Comment: A better solution is to have pooled listeners for each queue.  Size the pools to meet the SLO.

Comment: The problem with pooled dedicated listeners is that I am not making optimum utilization of my resources, for e.g. if on a given day I have very few priority 1 messages and thousands of priority 2 messages, given I have few pooled listeners for priority 2, I am not able to utilize the CPU capabilities

Comment: Who cares about optimum as long as you get the job done?  You're worried about the wrong things.

Comment: I agree duffymo, but can I have like 400\500 concurrent consumers per JMS queue

Comment: That's nothing.  Have you actually tried anything and measured?  I'm guessing you have no idea what your real throughput is or what affects it.

Answer (score 2):

First off, the requirement to process within 1 second is not going to be dependent on your messaging approach, but more about the actual processing of the message and the raw CPUs available.  Picking up 100s of messages per second from a queue is child's play, the JMS provider is most likely not the issue.  Depending on your deployment platform (Tomcat, Mule, JEE, whatever), there should be a way to have n listeners to scale up appropriately.  Because the messages exist on the queue until you pick it up, doubtful you'll run out of memory.  I've done these apps, processed many more messages without problems.

Second, number of strategies for prioritizing messages, not necessarily requiring different queues, using priorities.  I'm leaning towards using message priorities and message filters, where one group of listeners take care of the highest priority messages and another listener filters off lower priority but makes sure it does enough to get them out within a minute.

You could also do something where a lower priority message gets rewritten back to the same queue with a higher priority, based on how close to 1 minute you are.  I know that sounds wrong, but reading/writing from JMS has very little overhead (at least compared to do the equivalent, column-driven database transactions), but the listener for lower priority messages could just continually increase the priority until it has to be processed.

Or simpler, just have more listeners on the high priority queue/messages than the lower priority ones, and imbalance in number of processes for messages might be all it needs.

Lots of possibilities, time for a PoC.

Comment: there are number of strategies that I suggested, just need to work through and see which one is doable

Comment: Thanks for your reply Scott. I agree that reading hundreds of JMS messages off the queue is not going to be difficult but the question is how do I prioritize between the 2 queues.  When you talk about Message priorities and Message filters, are you saying I use just 1 queue instead of 2 queues and then use JMS message priority and Message filters to process the messages?   With the approach where I have more listeners for higher priority and less listeners for lower priority, my CPU utilization will be low on days when I have more lower priority messages. I will be using IBM MQ & WAS